# Teardown function after TestMain m.Run() is never called

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have the following testing code where I am testing some endpoints and database (mongoDB) features. I am using mgo package and I have some abstractions to get a new session copy each time I access the database.

```
package resolvers_test

import (
    //various imports here
)

func setup() {
    log.Println("ENTER SETUP\n")
    customerIndex := mgo.Index{
        Key:        []string{"email"},
        Unique:     true,
        Background: true,
        Sparse:     true,
    }

    session := db.GetSession().Copy()
    defer session.Close()
    customerCollection := session.DB("testDB").C("customerCollection")

    customerCollection.EnsureIndex(customerIndex)
    log.Println("EXIT SETUP")

}

func shutdown() {
    log.Println("ENTER SHUTDOWN\n")
    session := db.GetSession().Copy()
    defer session.Close()
    session.DB("testDB").DropDatabase()
    log.Println("EXIT SHUTDOWN\n")
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    setup()
    code := m.Run()
    shutdown()
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

In the `shutdown()` function I have placed a piece of code that supposedly should delete the test database, however while `setup()` function is called (I know that because it creates the Index) the `shutdown()` function is never called. Any ideas?

EDIT: I added log statements when entering end exiting setup() and shutdown() and the console log. The functions are both reachable. The log is the following:

```
2018/02/10 09:09:54 ENTER SETUP

2018/02/10 09:09:55 EXIT SETUP
=== RUN   TestCreateCustomer
--- PASS: TestCreateCustomer (0.14s)
        a_customerProfile_test.go:108: Create Customer successful
=== RUN   TestCustomerProfile
--- PASS: TestCustomerProfile (0.27s)
        a_customerProfile_test.go:152: Customer Profile Test Successful
PASS
2018/02/10 09:09:55 ENTER SHUTDOWN

2018/02/10 09:09:55 EXIT SHUTDOWN
```

Comment: The usual culprit is a log.Fatal call in a test

Comment: @JimB i don’t have any panics in this test package

Comment: Can you add a log statement in the `shutdown()` function to see if it actually reaches that code? If not, I'm guessing that there are test cases that we don't have that are preventing the program from running. Start commenting all of the test cases out and adding them back in one at a time until you find the culprit. If you still need help, try posting just that test case (or simplify it until you have the most simple version of your test that still does not delete the database).

Answer (score 1):

You are stating `defer session.Close()` in `setup()`

Hence `session := db.GetSession().Copy()` in `shutdown()` will get a new session without any DB selected.

Make `setup()` returns `*mgo.Session` and state `defer session.Close()` in `TestMain()`

Comment: Mgo creates a main Session object tied to the mongos. Session is the object used to select one of the many databases that exist on the server, not the other way around. Also defer statements are guaranteed to run just before the function exits. Even if this particular statement is not run the only problem would be a dangling session copy.